# Окно панели элементов не активна в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

во время начала пользования vs они были активны, а потом резко перестали, в чем может быть проблема? спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так vs code или visual studio? это немного разные вещи.

Comment: просто  visual studio

Comment: Вы создали новое приложение или это случилось с текущим, в котором раньше работало?

Comment: в текущем, и в новых их тоже нет

Comment: чудес  не бывает. Возможно, студия обновилась, может ещё что то сделали.

Comment: хэх спасибо, вот только что посмотрел остальные элементы, и нашел активные, но там название самой папки на англ, и все работает, и я тут вспомнил что  именно с этой папкой работал, но это не отменяет того,почему те не работают

Comment: то есть, в папке с кириллическим именем не работает? интересно. попробуйте создать пару тестовых проектов в разных вариантах названий папок (с только английскими словами и в смеси) и проверьте эту гипотезу